# Firebase functions auth user onCreate uni test

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, sinon

How would you achieve stubbing the below call?

I have managed to stub the user object

```
admin.firestore().collection('roles').where('role', '==', 'unassigned');
```

**Functions**

```
exports.userRegistration = functions.auth.user()
.onCreate((user, context) => {    
    let unassignedRole;
    let roleRef = admin.firestore().collection('roles').where('role', '==', 'unassigned');
    await roleRef.get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            unassignedRole = doc.ref;
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
    });

    await admin.firestore().collection('users').add({
        firstName: user.firstName || "",
        lastName: user.lastName || "",
        fullName: user.displayName || "",
        profilePic: user.photoURL || "",
        email: user.email,
        dateRegistered: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        role: unassignedRole
    });
});
```

**Unit Test**

```
describe('Cloud Functions', () => {
    let myFunctions, adminInitStub;

    before(() => {
        adminInitStub = sinon.stub(admin, 'initializeApp');
        myFunctions = require('../index');
    });

    after(() => {
        adminInitStub.restore();
        test.cleanup();
    });

    describe('userRegistration', () => {
        it('should write the newly registered user to /users', () => {
            const mockUser = test.auth.makeUserRecord({
                email: "test@email.com"
            });

            const wrapped = test.wrap(myFunctions.userRegistration);
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure it's `firestore().collection('users')` not `firestore.collection('users')`? https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Firestore.html#collection, So what's your implementation of `admin.firestore()`?

Comment: Hey, if I use admin.firestore.collection I get a TypeError message, `admin.firestore.collection` is not a function.